# many to many relationship help

Tags: sql

I'm having trouble designing my table.

My current relationship is to represent exercise routines and days of the week. I have a routine table that is one-to-many with a day table and day table is many-to-many with  a exercise table. Because a routine consist of many days and different days consist of different set of exercises.

Tables:
routine,
day,
day_exercise (junction table for many to many relationship),
exercise

The problem I have is the day and exercise relationship, where I want to have a sort field, so that the user have to do the set of exercise for the day in a certain order. I can't put a sort field in the junction table (day_exercise table), because it won't be a pure many to many relationship any more. Another reason is because MVC frameworks does support composite primary keys, and creating a auto increment field for the junction table is bad design.

I believe the solution is either I make a third table, exercise sort, and so the junction table would have 3 primary keys instead of just 2 pk of just days and exercise. Is this the correct way or do I have to just rethink the relationship?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can the sort order be pre-defined?  In other words, will certain types of exercise always be performed before others, or will each routine have a potentially random order?

Answer (score 1):

If you need a sort column, and it seems you really do, then it should almost certainly go in the table that stores each user's exercises for that day. I'd expect to see a table something like this.

```
user_id  day  exercise_id sort_order
--
1        Mon  32          1
1        Mon  33          2
...
1        Mon  13          9
...
1        Fri  32          1
...
1        Fri  17          9
2        Mon  36          1
```

and so on. But it's not clear to me which table this might be in your schema.  I think the columns (day, exercise_id) would have a foreign key reference to the table day_exercise. (Although I'm not sure I see the point in a table that contains days and exercises without also containing a user's id. Not saying there can't be a good reason for one, just that I don't see the reason from what you posted.)

Comment: The reason why I don't need a user_id field is because this is just a list of exercise people do through out the week. I don't need the user id for the routine list other than the creator of the routine, which is in the routine table.

Comment: Then you can drop the user_id column. Primary key would be (day, exercise_id) if exercises don't repeat during a day. If sort_order is determined by (day, exercise_id), then it stays in this table. If sort_order is determined by exercise_id, it should go in the table of exercises.